# Get random words from android dictionary

Tags: android, dictionary

I am kind of learning android...and I would like to know if there is a way to access 3 letter words or 4 letter words or some specif type of words at random from the android User Dictionary class??Considering the fact that android has an auto correct feature I'm guessing it also has a dictionary in it...thus how do I use that...where can I find a proper tutorial?

i have no idea about the code...searched around a lot...please help me with the code and also the explanation possibly :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to access the android dictionary but you can have a "custom" dictionary as a txt file in the app's assets folder. This [link](http://www.puzzlers.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=solving%3awordlists%3aabout%3astart/) has several word lists from around 20,000 words to 200,000 words. You could find more lists with google.

Afterwards, you can read the txt file and add it to an Array List if it matches the word length. A random word can then be selected from the dictionary list. The following code will create the dictionary and select a random word from it.

```
private ArrayList<String> dictionary;
private int wordLength; //Set elsewhere

private void createDictionary(){
    dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();

    BufferedReader dict = null; //Holds the dictionary file
    AssetManager am = this.getAssets();

    try {
        //dictionary.txt should be in the assets folder.
        dict = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(am.open("dictionary.txt")));

        String word;
        while((word = dict.readLine()) != null){
            if(word.length() == wordLength){
                dictionary.add(word);
            }
        }

     } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

    try {
        dict.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Precondition: the dictionary has been created.
private String getRandomWord(){
    return dictionaryList.get((int)(Math.random() * dictionaryList.size()));
}
```